# How to upsert with not unique fields in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I'm trying to perform `upsert` (model, sqlite were chosen for demonstration purposes):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite import insert
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, declarative_base

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:", echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    email: Mapped[str]


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session() as session:
    stmt = insert(User).values(name='New Name', email='user@example.com')
    stmt = stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
        index_elements=[User.email],
        set_={'name': stmt.excluded.name}
    )
    session.execute(stmt.returning(User.id))
    session.commit()
```

The code above fails:

> 2024-01-30 23:32:07,956 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
> 2024-01-30 23:32:07,956 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA
> main.table_info("users") 2024-01-30 23:32:07,956 INFO
> sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] () 2024-01-30 23:32:07,957 INFO
> sqlalchemy.engine.Engine PRAGMA temp.table_info("users") 2024-01-30
> 23:32:07,958 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] () 2024-01-30
> 23:32:07,959 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine  CREATE TABLE users (  id
> INTEGER NOT NULL,     name VARCHAR NOT NULL,      email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY (id) )
>
> 2024-01-30 23:32:07,959 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key
> 0.00017s] () 2024-01-30 23:32:07,961 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine CREATE INDEX ix_users_id ON users (id) 2024-01-30 23:32:07,961 INFO
> sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key 0.00017s] () 2024-01-30 23:32:07,962
> INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT 2024-01-30 23:32:07,965 INFO
> sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit) 2024-01-30 23:32:07,967 INFO
> sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (?, ?)
> ON CONFLICT (email) DO UPDATE SET name = excluded.name RETURNING id
> 2024-01-30 23:32:07,967 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [no key
> 0.00022s] ('New Name', 'user@example.com') 2024-01-30 23:32:07,967 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK Traceback (most recent call
> last):   File
> "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1969, in _exec_single_context
> self.dialect.do_execute(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
> line 922, in do_execute
> cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlite3.OperationalError: ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/sa/upsert.py",
> line 44, in 
> session.execute(stmt.returning(User.id))   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
> line 2308, in execute
> return self._execute_internal(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py",
> line 2190, in _execute_internal
> result: Result[Any] = compile_state_cls.orm_execute_statement(   File
> "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/bulk_persistence.py",
> line 1276, in orm_execute_statement
> result = conn.execute(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1416, in execute
> return meth(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py",
> line 516, in _execute_on_connection
> return connection._execute_clauseelement(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1639, in _execute_clauseelement
> ret = self._execute_context(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1848, in _execute_context
> return self._exec_single_context(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1988, in _exec_single_context
> self._handle_dbapi_exception(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 2343, in _handle_dbapi_exception
> raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e   File
> "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py",
> line 1969, in _exec_single_context
> self.dialect.do_execute(   File "/Users/alber.aleksandrov/PycharmProjects/Playground/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py",
> line 922, in do_execute
> cursor.execute(statement, parameters) sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) ON
> CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint
> [SQL: INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES (?, ?) ON CONFLICT
> (email) DO UPDATE SET name = excluded.name RETURNING id] [parameters:
> ('New Name', 'user@example.com')] (Background on this error at:
> https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

I cannot make email unique. How to do upsert? I use SQLAlchemy 2.

Comment: There has to be some kind of constraint for `ON CONFLICT` to work (precisely which constraints may be used may vary by RDBMS).